# C++ while loop, testing multiple arrays' subscripts

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

How do you test multiple arrays in a while loop to see if their subscript values do not equal a certain value?

I also need to separate the arrays to end the loop when all of the subscripts in either array equal 0. This is what I thought would work, but it doesn't.

```
while(
      (pl_health[0] !=0 && pl_health[1] !=0 && pl_health[2] !=0 &&
       pl_health[3] !=0 && pl_health[4] !=0 && pl_health[5] !=0) ||
      (enemy[0].health !=0 && enemy[1].health !=0 && enemy[2].health !=0 &&
       enemy[3].health !=0 && enemy[4].health !=0 && enemy[5].health !=0)
     )
```

As you can see I tried to separate the 2 arrays using paranthesese and the or operator. The program runs free of errors, but the loop does not even iterate once. Even when some of the subscripts are not equal to 0.

Comment: This code is valid, perhaps your ideas about what it is supposed to do are not right. In English it is "while either all players have health, or all enemies have health".

Comment: You could have something like `while (p1_alive() || enemies_alive())` instead of an "hard-to-maintain" huge condition, given that the two cases are defined as functions. It would be much easier and less likely to give surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should switch the conditions, most likely (depending on what you are trying to do). One of the commenters pointed out that your logic is "proceed only while every player has health or every enemy has health." I am leaving the other part of my answer intact, as it is still relevant. Here is the while loop that I think expresses the condition you want, though.

```
while(
      (pl_health[0] !=0 || pl_health[1] !=0 || pl_health[2] !=0 ||
       pl_health[3] !=0 || pl_health[4] !=0 || pl_health[5] !=0) &&
      (enemy[0].health !=0 || enemy[1].health !=0 || enemy[2].health !=0 ||
       enemy[3].health !=0 || enemy[4].health !=0 || enemy[5].health !=0)
     )
```

A while loop with so many checks in the condition isn't the way to go here. A better approach might be something like:

```
bool playerAlive = true, enemyAlive = true;

while (playerAlive && enemyAlive) {
    // game logic etc

    playerAlive = false;
    enemyAlive = false;

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        if (pl_health[i] != 0) {
            playerAlive = true;
        }

        if (enemy[i].health != 0) {
            enemyAlive = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Mind you, the array approach to storing health is probably only suitable for a simple/small game at best. And of course you would probably want to remove the magic "6" from the for loop and have it be a constant.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I figured the solution was something simple. Still new to programming, so don't have all the ends ironed out yet.

Comment: No problem -- I still feel new to it quite often myself :)